# Why can't this ManagedObjectContext be passed directly into a SwiftUI view's environment?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, xcode12

When you start a new SwiftUI project in Xcode 12, and tick the 'Use Core Data' checkbox, you get some template code that'll set up a SwiftUI view with a *managed object context* injected into it through an *environment value*.

Like this:

```swift
struct CoreDataTestApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, the `persistenceController` is a `PersistenceController` object (struct) that gives access to an `NSManagedObjectContext`, which is needed to work with Core Data in a SwiftUI view. Here's the relevant code:

```swift
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataTest")
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            ...
        })
    }
}
```

This all works; it's the default/template code in Xcode 12. However, when you make the following change, it won't work anymore:

```
struct CoreDataTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

You'll get the following error: **CoreData: error: No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Item' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?**

*Why?*

I'm thinking that, since `PersistenceController.shared` is static and not weak, it's retained strongly, so memory management shouldn't be an issue. The `persistenceController` is merely a 'temporary' property – why can't you change one for the other? My guess is that it's got something to do with how the object is passed into the environment, but I'm not sure.

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

--
EDIT:

Core Data is used for the `@FetchRequest` in `ContentView`, here:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
...
```

Comment: Do you have an entity `Item` in your Core Data model?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes. This 'Item' is added by default as part of the template.

Comment: The template seems really strange here. I don't believe PersistenceController should be  a struct. It really should be a class; it has identity. A "shared" struct doesn't make sense, and I'm afraid you're recreating it every time the view hierarchy is reevaluated. I expect the sample code "works" because it's copying the shared instance rather than making a new one. (But if you care about the difference between copying and making a new one, it shouldn't be a struct.)

Comment: @RobNapier Caught your answer before, found it a good explanation. It's the default template for Xcode 12.1, new Swift / SwiftUI / SwiftUI App project + 'Use Core Data' – just confirmed, it is a struct. Switching to `class` does not solve the error. (I'll check if 12.2 is any different.)

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint on `init` and make sure that it's being called exactly once, still. If it's called multiple times, that would give the symptom you're describing.

Comment: The error is logged before the breakpoint on `init` hits. Does this imply that the MOC is used/read before it's initialized, because `loadPersistentStores()` is async? It's still a racy condition – with the property, init and loadPersistentStores would happen sooner than when environment is set on ContentView.

Comment: It's very strange that this `init` would never run at all, but you're still accessing Core Data. I'm definitely concerned about race conditions with `container.loadPersistentStores`, since the system isn't ready to go until that completes, and I don't see anything in the template or your change that verifies that. I don't know if the template's pattern is just getting lucky, or if Apple is doing something special to make sure the Core Data stack is initialized before evaluating `body`. (I don't know if a lightweight migration would impact the timing, for example.)

Comment: Core Data is accessed in `ContentView` via `@FetchRequest`, which relies on an env value for `\.managedObjectContext` to be set first. Passing the 'shared' object will init, kick off `loadPersistentStores()`, which is too late, b/c fetch request already accessed CD. The template with the property on `App` works, but because it's still a race condition, yes, it's a question of when and for how long. What's the right play here?

Comment: I've filed several Feedbacks to Apple on their Xcode templates so I'm not surprised. The app UI completely failed without fixes when using Core Data + iCloud SwiftUI app template the other day (can't remember if it was the 12.3 beta or 12.2 release). In this case I'd agree with @RobNapier, the template is at best poor if not actually broken.